# Python JSON import to MongoDB from ZIP files

Tags: python, json, mongodb

I have a script that gets all of the .zip files from a folder, then one by one, opens the zip file, loads the content of the JSON file inside and imports this to MongoDB.

The error I am getting is `the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'TextIOWrapper'`

The code is:

```
import json
import logging
import logging.handlers
import os
from logging.config import fileConfig
from pymongo import MongoClient


def import_json():
    try:
        client = MongoClient('5.57.62.97', 27017)
        db = client['vuln_sets']
        coll = db['vulnerabilities']
        basepath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        filepath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(basepath, ".."))
        archive_filepath = filepath + '/vuln_files/'
        filedir = os.chdir(archive_filepath)
        for item in os.listdir(filedir):
            if item.endswith('.json'):
                file_name = os.path.abspath(item)
                fp = open(file_name, 'r')
                json_data = json.loads(fp)
                for vuln in json_data:
                  print(vuln)
                  coll.insert(vuln)
                os.remove(file_name)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception(e)
```

I can get this working to use a single file but not multiple, i.e. to do one file I wrote:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
import json
import pymongo

archive = ZipFile("vulners_collections/cve.zip")
archived_file = archive.open(archive.namelist()[0])
archive_content = archived_file.read()
archived_file.close()

connection = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost")
db=connection.vulnerability
vuln1 = db.vulnerability_collection
vulners_objects = json.loads(archive_content)

for item in vulners_objects:
    vuln1.insert(item)
```

Comment: Try replacing `file.open(...) / file.close` with `with open(file, "r")`

Comment: I have no experience with glob, but from skimming the doc I get the impression your `archive_files` is a simple list of file-paths as strings, correct? You can not perform actions like `.open` on string (thus your error), so try to open the file with the command above.

Comment: This doesn't work, I just get the error of `''str' object has no attribute 'read'`

Answer (score 1):

From my comment above:

I have no experience with glob, but from skimming the doc I get the impression your archive_files is a simple list of file-paths as strings, correct? You can not perform actions like .open on string (thus your error), so try changing your code to this:

```
    ...
    archive_filepath = filepath + '/vuln_files/'
    archive_files = glob.glob(archive_filepath + "/*.zip")

    for file in archive_files:
        with open(file, "r") as currentFile:
            file_content = currentFile.read()
            vuln_content = json.loads(file_content)
            for item in vuln_content:
                coll.insert(item)
   ...
```

`file` is NOT a file object or anything but just a simple string. So you cant perform methods on it that are not supported by string.

Comment: That got me further, I now have issues changing then encoding from UTF8 to windows-1252 as this is what the JSON file is encoded as. I tried using `currentFile.encoding = 'windows-1252'` but this just throws a readonly attribute error

Comment: @Luke use with open(file, "r", encoding="windows-1252")

Comment: Turns out I forgot to unzip the file first! but now my script runs with no errors yet I get nothing in MongoDB nor does a print statement I added do anything. I;ve edited the code above

Comment: @Luke can you give an example for your input file? Check the length of `archiveList` and `vuln_content` if there is data in it at all.

Comment: I've updated the code as I processed the Zipfiles separately and got the raw .json files so now I am trying to loop through these

Comment: @Luke please provide an example of your json file

Answer (score 0):

You are redefining your iterator by setting it to the result of the namelist method.  You need a for loop within the for to go through the contents of the zip file and of course a new iterator variable.

Comment: I tried creating a new for loop but think I have this wrong: `        for file in archive_files:
            open_files = file.open(file.namelist()[0])
            for open_file in open_files:
                file_content = file.read()
                file.close
                vuln_content = json.loads(file_content)`

Answer (score 0):

Isn't file.close wrong and the correct call is file.close().

U can use json.load() to load file directly, instead of json.loads()

```
fp = open(file_name, 'r')
json_data = json.load(fp)
fp.close()
```